# How do I compare yields on an annuity?

Tags: annuity, lump-sum

I want to compare two financial products, but run the same time and get invested in the same amounts. Taxes etc are assumed to be the same for both.

Product A: pays a livelong annuity after x years.

Product B: pays a lump sum after x years.

If I try to calculate the yield, its easy for product B because I can compare the investment and the lump sum, however the yield for product A gets better each year the older I get.

If I dont know how long I receive the annuity i.e. how old I get, is there a way to compare the yields?

Comment: Determine your expected lifetime using your existing age, relevant health information and country. There are such mortality statistics for most countries.

Comment: You'll have to solve the insurance problem of computing the net present value of a life annuity using a mortality table.  You can approximate this using your expected life span.